# JSOM or REST to display list items according to permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to figure out how to display list items in SharePoint App according to permissions for users. I have 10 items in the list, but only 5 are visible (read access) to certain users. I have list view should show items according to permissions (Admins see all, normal user only selected items). 
Do I understand correctly, that SharePoint Hosted App trying to access list items will do the same for each user according to his permissions because it basically reads data with logged in user's permissions?
I am sorry to ask, but I do not have two separate accounts to try this out and I do not know how to formulate this question to find it on Google.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , you are correct. The REST or JSOM calls to get list data function according to logged in user's permission. If you are admin, you will see all items, but if you are normal user, you will see only those items on which you have read permission.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to the app model and that's what I understood. Thank you so much for the confirmation. ;)